# AWS Cognito JS how to allow access to s3 object (a specific html page)

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I have 3 html files in an s3 hosted website, a register.html, login.html and a dashboard.html

The registration and logging in work and I end up with an an access token.

How do I restrict access to the dashboard.html then somehow use the access token to allow access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using JavaScript without Restricting Access**

For this kind of a problem, a straight forward approach is to load the dashboard.html and have a JavaScript in dashboard.html body to toggle the display of content by verifying if the user is already logged in or not (e.g, Checking a Cognito JWT token in LocalStorage) and redirect to login.html for unauthenticated users.

Note: This approach will be also useful if you plan to use AWS Cognito UserPools Hosted UI.

**Restricting Access**

If you plan to go ahead with restricting access to dashboard.html you can use CloudFront Signed Cookies to achieve it as follows.

- Setup S3 access through AWS CloudFront (Creating an Origin Access Identity - OAI) and make the S3 buckets private (For all three pages). While you register the S3 origins, you OAI with the wizard.
- Create three different behaviors for each html file.
- For the login.html and register.html behaviors, set **Restrict Viewer Access(Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies) to No**
- For dashboard.html only, set **Restrict Viewer Access(Use Signed URLs or
  Signed Cookies) to Yes**
- When the user tries to access dashboard.html directly (Without Login), CloudFront will return an error. Therefore configure AWS CloudFront error response to Login.html.
- Create an API Gateway and Lambda endpoint to validate the Cognito JWT Token from Login Page and create a [Signed Cookie in Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) and return it in setCookie header.
- The browser will send the Cookie header and CloudFront will allow loading dashboard.html when the Cookie is present.

Comment: Are there any good resources to use as a reference? I'm haven't found any in-depth guides, that aren't in angular or react

Comment: Quick question, how do I verify the jwt token? Thanks

Comment: Check the "Using ID Tokens and Access Tokens in your Web APIs" section in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html